# Stripe_InvalidRequestError: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once

Tags: forms

I'm trying to integrate [Stripe’s Checkout and PHP](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php) into a simple module and I've got the following:

```
Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

if (!empty($form_state['input'])) {
  $input = $form_state['input'];
  // Create a Customer
  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
    "card" => $input['stripeToken'],
    "email" => $input['stripeEmail'],
  ));

  // Charge the Customer instead of the card
  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 4900,
    "currency" => "GBP",
    "customer" => $customer->id,
  ));
}
else {
  $data = array(
    "data-key" => $stripe['publishable_key'],
    "data-name" => variable_get("site_name", ""),
    "data-amount" => 4900,
    "data-currency" => "GBP",
  );

  $form['stripe'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" ' . join(' ', array_map(function($sKey) use ($data) {
      if (is_bool($data[$sKey])) {
        return $data[$sKey] ? $sKey : '';
      }
      return $sKey . '="' . $data[$sKey] . '"';
    }, array_keys($data))) . '></script>'
  );
}
```

Everything is working great so far apart from when I call $charge = Stripe_Charge::create I get an error returned *Stripe_InvalidRequestError: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once* but I don't understand how my code would be using the token more than once.

Although I get this error, in my dashboard at Stripe the payment is successfully processed, I'm using the [Stripe API Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have figured it out, when the form code is running, it runs multiple times, to stop it I added a variable to $form_state so the top of my code above becomes:

```
Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

if (!empty($form_state['input']) && !isset($form_state['processed'])) {
  $form_state['processed'] = TRUE;
```